# How can I make my custom templates respect permissions?

Tags: templates, permissions

I use the Members plugin to manage permissions on my site. For standard templates, it works great - when the user doesn't have permission to see a page, they get the following message:

> Sorry, but you do not have permission to view this content.

How can I make sure I still get this message in my custom templates? Which tag do I need to include?

**EDIT.** Template source:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Stats
*/
?>


<?php
get_header();
?>

<div id="main">

<div id="contentwrapper">
  <div class="topPost">
    <h2 class="topTitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="topContent">
      <p>Listeners are counted every minute. The green line is the <b>maximum</b> during any given time period. The red area is the <b>average</b> number of listeners during the same time period.</p>
      <h3>Listeners over the last hour</h3>
      <img class="alignnone" title="Listeners over the last hour" src="<?php echo get_graph(60,60); ?>" alt="" width="481" height="149" />
      <hr/>
      <h3>Listeners over the last day</h3>
      <img class="alignnone" title="Listeners over the last day" src="<?php echo get_graph(3600,24); ?>" alt="" width="481" height="149" />
      <hr/>
      <h3>Listeners over the last week</h3>
      <img class="alignnone" title="Listeners over the last week" src="<?php echo get_graph(86400,7); ?>" alt="" width="481" height="149" />
    </div>
    <div class="cleared"></div>
  <div class="cleared"></div>
  </div> <!-- Closes topPost -->
</div> <!-- Closes contentwrapper-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<div class="cleared"></div>

</div><!-- Closes Main -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Note: The purpose of this template is to act as a front end for a shell script. Any content on the database is irrelevant, so there's no loop. (Though including a dummy loop didn't seem to help.)

Comment: Please add the template tags you use in your custom template to your question.

Comment: I've added the whole source for your enjoyment.

Answer (score 3):

Message you quoted is being generated by `members_content_permissions_protect()` function. By default it is used as a filter on `the_content()` and `the_excerpt()` functions. Since your custom template doesn't use these - there is no case for function to run.

Try something like this in template:

```
$content = 'Content to protect';
echo members_content_permissions_protect( $content );
```

Another idea:

```
$protected = members_content_permissions_protect( false );

if( false !== $protected ) {

    echo $protected;
}
else {

    //template stuff goes here
}
```

Comment: That's basically why I asked which template tags are in use (or not). I already suspected something like that.

Comment: This gives me the right message, but doesn't hide the contents of the template. Is there a conditional form? Or will I have to convert my template to a PHP string?

Comment: You will have to convert template to a PHP string, at least for my example. I suggest you ask plugin's developer for recommended usage to protect non-loop content.

Comment: Got another idea for a snippet, see my answer. But suggestion to check with developer still stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the userlevels system, youc an find more information on roles levels and capabilities here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

See here for how the old 'roles' map onto the user levels system:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#User_Levels

You can further define in your templates wether a user of a given role can view a page or not using the following:

```
global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo();

if ($current_user->user_level < 8) {
    // stuff that is only visible to users lower than level 8
}
```

Also bear in mind:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... }
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Using these you should be able to control who can see what, and at what level of access they need to  see it

Comment: Numerical User Levels tend to out-date. I don't think it's a god advise to use them. Next to that, if the proper template tags are used, you can safe all the hassle to code some logic on your own.